# Multiplication of polynomials of two different variables in Scilab

Tags: scilab, polynomials

Is there any specific method available to multiply two polynomials of different variable in `Scilab`? Because when I do multiplication in `Scilab` the result is coming only with one variable.

```
x = poly(0, "x");
y = poly(0, "y");

m1 = 1+x^2+x^3;
m2 = y;

p = m1*m2;

Result:  p  = 

   3   4
x +x  +x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scilab only supports polynomials of one variable. Since there is no concept of a polynomial of two variables, the multiplication `m1*m2` should really throw an error, it appears to be an oversight if it doesn't.

If you need to manipulate multivariable polynomials, Scilab is not the right tool to use. Consider [SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/index.html).